# Why does my Window take a few clicks to actually close even though the event fires?

Tags: java, libgdx, events

I am pretty new to game dev (and libgdx + scene2d specifically), I am creating a dialog system for an rpg game and obviously a dialog window has a close button to close a dialog but for some reason it takes few clicks to close it ([see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rusDnsEtD3E)).

I have added `System.out.println(Actor.class)` to where the listener executes:

[image: Events fired as planned]

As you can see the events fired as planned!

Here is my listener code:

```
closeButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
    System.out.println(Actor.class);
    event.getListenerActor().getParent().addAction(Actions.hide());        
  }
});
```

Please send help,  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Guys who recommended checking whether stage.act() is firing properly were correct!

This is my original code in Hud.java(the class that renders the hud layer where I try to display dialogs):

```
  public void render(float delta) {
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }
```

And this is the code that fixed it:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    stage.draw();
    stage.act(delta);
}
```

It was a simple mistake, my bad, it is only logical to draw your things and then update them.

Thanks everyone for the imput

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ClickListener:

```
    closeButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        System.out.println(Actor.class);
        event.getListenerActor().getParent().addAction(Actions.hide());             
    }

});
```

Also, check if you call method stage.act() in render. Without that action will not work. Eventually you can use setVisible(false) on actor.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I googled prior to asking this here, community seems to have a hard time deciding weather its clicklistener or changelistener after all